# Saved Matlab movie file only plays the last frame

Tags: matlab, animation

I made a movie in Matlab, and when I run my code, the movie runs fine and looks great, but when I attach the video on an email, the video appears to show only the last frame of the movie.

In my for loop with all the plotting code, I used a getframe command, with variable G, before ending the loop:

```
G = getframe;
```

Then I wrote:

```
v = VideoWriter('my movie.avi','Motion JPEG AVI');

v.Quality = 100;

open(v)

writeVideo(v,G)

close(v)
```

Then I see the movie created and saved in my folder.  I go to attach the movie to an email, open it up, and see that the movie only has the last frame.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: To see a movie....you need softwares lik ewindows media player, vlc etc. In email obviously you can see only a frame. Down the movie from e-mail and see the video..does it play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MATLAB [`getframe()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) function returns the current frame, and you write it into the variable `G` in your for-loop. This *overwrites* `G` in each iteration, so at all times in your program, `G` will contain the last frame only. When you write it to a video file, that video will also contain only that one last frame, as you noticed.

The solution is to create an array of frames, as shown in the [example on how to record videos](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html#bup_8ge-1) using `getframe()` in the MATLAB help pages:

```
movie_frames(N) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);    % pre-allocate frames struct
for k=1:N
    % Your plotting code here

    movie_frames(k) = getframe();
end
```

The [`writeVideo()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.writevideo.html) function is actually designed to work with such arrays of frames, this makes saving the video as simple as

```
v = VideoWriter('test_video.avi');
v.open();
v.writeVideo(movie_frames);
v.close();
```

Comment: @JalapenoNachos you don't need the for loop at all, see the edit to my question. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: This means at least one of your frames is not created - make sure that in each iteration of the for-loop you get a valid figure and capture it with `getframe`. For debugging, you can e.g. call `imshow(movie_frames(k).cdata); pause();` inside your loop to verify that everything worked.

Comment: I often use constructs like `values=1:round(N/K):N;` and then `for idx=1:numel(values); value_i = values(idx); end`- i.e. first create a vector of  values of interest, and then iterate over the index in that array and not the value itself.